# How can I set a grid in a GWTHighchart chart?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-highcharts

Well, I'm trying to add those auxiliar vertical and horizontal lines to my chart (grid), but I'm not sure if that's only a Highchart feature or it can be made with GWTHighchart too.
P.S.: That picture is from a question (not mine) posted here at SO, but it shows what I'm trying to do.

[image: Example of what I'm trying to accomplish]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  See the Axis api setGridLineXXX methods, eg
http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/apidocs/org/moxieapps/gwt/highcharts/client/Axis.html#setGridLineWidth(java.lang.Number)

Also, if the specific feature you want to access is not exposed by GWTHighchart then you may be able to use JSNI methods to access it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But it only shows the main grid lines (one line per each tick), I want that it also shows some lines between them (like the picture in the question).

Comment: see setMinorGridLineWidth

Comment: It didn't work... I use that method but nothing happend with the grid. I also changed the minor color to black: setMinorGridLineColor("#000000"), but without results.

Comment: have a look at the javadocs - you probably need to set the minor grid ticks

Comment: Finally, it shows every line... Here are the code lines that made it work. Thanks a lot.

chart.getXAxis().setGridLineWidth(1);
chart.getXAxis().setMinorTickIntervalAuto();
chart.getYAxis().setGridLineWidth(1);
chart.getYAxis().setMinorTickIntervalAuto();